# EWS Use credentials from logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, exchangewebservices, form-authentication

I have a ASP MVC web application which uses Form Authentication. Users Have to log in with their AD username and password. I only store the AD username in a cookie not the password.

In this application users need to add contacts to outlook. I'm using EWS and the code works perfectly if I use my own AD username and password.

**Code sample:**

```
       var eS = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = new WebCredentials("Username", "Password", "Domain"),
            TraceEnabled = true,
        };

        eS.AutodiscoverUrl("email");

        var contact = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact(eS)
        {
            GivenName = "Nanou",
            Surname = "Ponette",
        };

        contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = "00000000000";

        contact.Save();
```

The question I have is how can I make this work for every user that logs in?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Impersonation and Kerberos delegation see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2012/11/05/exchange-web-services-from-a-web-application-using-windows-authentication.aspx which has a sample for what you need to do.

Cheers
Glen